# What to identify whether textview content reached view end?

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to identify does textview's content inside or it does not fit.

By googling, I found this solution:

```
        tvContent.setText(tvContent.getText()+sb.toString());
        TextPaint paint = tvContent.getPaint();
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        String text = String.valueOf(tvContent.getText());
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), rect);
        boolean reached = rect.height() > tvContent.getHeight();
```

But it has false value for all tries - when it fits and when it does not fit. How actually to identify it fits or not?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8Tzq.png)
[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8jht.png)